# Play audio and video with a Pipeline in Gstreamer

Tags: python, c, gstreamer, pipeline

Is there a way make a pipeline that will play any video file (which will contain audio too)? I have tried linking elements like:

```
filesrc -> decodebin
```

along with

```
queue -> audioconvert -> autoaudiosink
```

and

```
queue -> autovideoconvert -> autovideosink
```

This causes two problems:

1. A `queue` cannot be linked to an `autovideoconvert`.
2. I have no idea how to implement a pad with the `"pad-added"` event, especially when the pipeline supports both audio and video.

I would like to know how to do this without the need for `gst.parse_launch`. Also, I want the pieline to work with any format I throw at it (like playbin), but cannot use a playbin as I will need to link other elements (`level` and `volume`).

Alternatively, is there a way to connect elements (such as `level`) to a playbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built an [example video player](https://gist.github.com/1381366) that makes use of the elements you described.

It should show you how to connect the pads to eachother dynamically.

```py
'''
Copyright (c) 2011 Joar Wandborg <http://wandborg.se>

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

---

- A response to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187257/play-audio-and-video-with-a-pipeline-in-gstreamer-python/8197837
- Like it? Buy me a beer! https://flattr.com/thing/422997/Joar-Wandborg
'''

import gst
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
import logging


logging.basicConfig()

_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class VideoPlayer(object):
    '''
    Simple video player
    '''

    source_file = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.loop = gobject.MainLoop()

        if kwargs.get('src'):
            self.source_file = kwargs.get('src')

        self.__setup()

    def run(self):
        self.loop.run()

    def stop(self):
        self.loop.quit()

    def __setup(self):
        _log.info('Setting up VideoPlayer...')
        self.__setup_pipeline()
        _log.info('Set up')

    def __setup_pipeline(self):
        self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline('video-player-pipeline')

        # Source element
        self.filesrc = gst.element_factory_make('filesrc')
        self.filesrc.set_property('location', self.source_file)
        self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc)

        # Demuxer
        self.decoder = gst.element_factory_make('decodebin2')
        self.decoder.connect('pad-added', self.__on_decoded_pad)
        self.pipeline.add(self.decoder)

        # Video elements
        self.videoqueue = gst.element_factory_make('queue', 'videoqueue')
        self.pipeline.add(self.videoqueue)

        self.autovideoconvert = gst.element_factory_make('autovideoconvert')
        self.pipeline.add(self.autovideoconvert)

        self.autovideosink = gst.element_factory_make('autovideosink')
        self.pipeline.add(self.autovideosink)

        # Audio elements
        self.audioqueue = gst.element_factory_make('queue', 'audioqueue')
        self.pipeline.add(self.audioqueue)

        self.audioconvert = gst.element_factory_make('audioconvert')
        self.pipeline.add(self.audioconvert)

        self.autoaudiosink = gst.element_factory_make('autoaudiosink')
        self.pipeline.add(self.autoaudiosink)

        self.progressreport = gst.element_factory_make('progressreport')
        self.progressreport.set_property('update-freq', 1)
        self.pipeline.add(self.progressreport)

        # Link source and demuxer
        linkres = gst.element_link_many(
            self.filesrc,
            self.decoder)

        if not linkres:
            _log.error('Could not link source & demuxer elements!\n{0}'.format(
                    linkres))

        linkres = gst.element_link_many(
            self.audioqueue,
            self.audioconvert,
            self.autoaudiosink)

        if not linkres:
            _log.error('Could not link audio elements!\n{0}'.format(
                    linkres))

        linkres = gst.element_link_many(
            self.videoqueue,
            self.progressreport,
            self.autovideoconvert,
            self.autovideosink)

        if not linkres:
            _log.error('Could not link video elements!\n{0}'.format(
                    linkres))

        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.connect('message', self.__on_message)

        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

    def __on_decoded_pad(self, pad, data):
        _log.debug('on_decoded_pad: {0}'.format(pad))

        if pad.get_caps()[0].to_string().startswith('audio'):
            pad.link(self.audioqueue.get_pad('sink'))
        else:
            pad.link(self.videoqueue.get_pad('sink'))

    def __on_message(self, bus, message):
        _log.debug(' - MESSAGE: {0}'.format(message))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    player = VideoPlayer(
        src='/home/joar/Videos/big_buck_bunny_1080p_stereo.avi')

    player.run()
```

Comment: Perfect, but I still have one more question: `new-decoded-pad` is deprecated. How do I use `pad-added`?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I've updated the code but haven't had time to test it yet, it should be very similar though - just another method.

Comment: It works but you have to put `if not sink_pad.is_linked():` before linking the pads. Also, I tested this with just audio, and it never plays. Do you know why?

Comment: It might be that the video part of the pipeline is pausing it all. You could skip the linking of the videos and audio elements based on if the source file contains audio or video.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without reconstructing the whole pipeline? If I just `add` the video elements to the pipeline without connecting them, it still has the same issue.

Comment: Helpful resources for debugging GStreamer; http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gst-running.html

Comment: I have decided to use `Discoverer` to determine whether or not the media contains video, and create a video or audio pipeline based of the result. I'll mark this question as solved, but if there is a better way to make a dynamic pipeline like this, please let me know. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Good choice on `Discoverer`. I really don't know if there are easier ways. I have seen some things about autoplugs on certain elements, but haven't looked into them yet - You're welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

`queue` is not a source element, you need to have either `uridecodebin` or `decodebin` or something simliar as the source element.

This is an example pipeline in the `gst-launch` format.

```
uridecodebin \
    uri="file:///home/joar/Dropbox/Music/04 - Deadmau5 - Clockwork (Jonas Steur Remix).mp3" \
! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

it means that in the pipeline there is

- `uridecodebin` - A decoding bin, capable of decoding whatever source file is compatible with GStreamer, with the `uri` property set to `file:///home/joar/Dropbox/Music/04 - Deadmau5 - Clockwork (Jonas Steur Remix).mp3`.
- `audioconvert` - Converts audio between different formats
- `autoaudiosink`

If needed, you could add a `queue` element between the `uridecodebin` and the `audioconvert`.

---

## Update

I can do what you describe using the following gst-launch command

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc \
    location="/home/joar/Dropbox/Skrillex vs. Adele - Set Fire to Everybody.mov" \
! decodebin name=dmux \
dmux. ! queue ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink \
dmux. ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Helpful, but it doesn't really answer my question. I have updated the pipeline layout to make things clearer.

Comment: I see, I have an idea on how to solve this, unfortunately I'm out of time for now. Please add a comment after this so that I get a notification, then I'll respond as soon as I'm in front of my PC.

Comment: All right, added a new section, if you're not using the gst-launch format, tell me and I'll help you perform it with `gst.element_factory_make()`.

Comment: Can you help me do this with `gst.element_factory_make()` please? Also, what exactly is the `dmux.` doing? Is it linking the sinks to the decodebin?

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatively** you could use GStreamer 1.0 by now.

There you'll find the new properties [`audio-filter`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--audio-filter) and [`video-filter`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-playbin.html#GstPlayBin--video-filter), which can be utilized to connect elements (such as `level)` to a playbin.

With Python GObject Introspection this could be done as easy as:

```
level = Gst.ElementFactory.make('level')

playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin")
playbin.props.audio_filter = level
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline to play audio & video on local:

gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=random-file.mpeg ! decodebin name=demux demux. ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink demux. ! queue ! audioconvert ! pulsesink

we can use autovideosink in place of xvimagesink.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you would have implemented this by now. But for others who looks at your question, my answer might help . The code is as follows

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import pygst
 pygst.require('0.10')
 import gst

 import pygtk
 pygtk.require('2.0')
 import gtk

 # this is very important, without this, callbacks from gstreamer thread
 # will messed our program up


 def on_new_decoded_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
     structure_name = pad.get_caps()[0].get_name()
     decode = pad.get_parent()
     pipeline = decode.get_parent()
     if structure_name.startswith("video"):
            queuev = pipeline.get_by_name('queuev')
        decode.link(queuev)
     if structure_name.startswith("audio"):
            queuea = pipeline.get_by_name('queuea')
    print queuea
        decode.link(queuea)


 def main():
     pipeline = gst.Pipeline('pipleline')

     filesrc = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc")
     filesrc.set_property('location', '/home/thothadri/Videos/nuclear.avi')

     decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode")

     queuev = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "queuev")

     sink = gst.element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink")

     queuea = gst.element_factory_make("queue", "queuea")

     convert = gst.element_factory_make('audioconvert', 'convert')

     sink_audio = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink_audio")

     pipeline.add(filesrc,decode,queuev,queuea,convert,sink,sink_audio)

     gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode)
     gst.element_link_many(queuev,sink)
     gst.element_link_many(queuea,convert,sink_audio)

     decode.connect("new-decoded-pad", on_new_decoded_pad)

     pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)



 main()
 gtk.gdk.threads_init()
 gtk.main()
```