# Receive Numpy Array Realtime from GStreamer

Tags: python, numpy, audio, video, gstreamer

I tried to receive numpy arrays from frame to frame in real-time from the GStreamer framework.

I already tried to use a pipeline like this (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187257/play-audio-and-video-with-a-pipeline-in-gstreamer-python/8197837 with modification) in Python:

```
self.filesrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesrc')
self.filesrc.set_property('location', self.source_file)
self.pipeline.add(self.filesrc)

# Demuxer
self.decoder = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decodebin')
self.decoder.connect('pad-added', self.__on_decoded_pad)
self.pipeline.add(self.decoder)

# Video elements
self.videoqueue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'videoqueue')
self.pipeline.add(self.videoqueue)

self.autovideoconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideoconvert')
self.pipeline.add(self.autovideoconvert)

self.autovideosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autovideosink')
self.pipeline.add(self.autovideosink)

# Audio elements
self.audioqueue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue', 'audioqueue')
self.pipeline.add(self.audioqueue)

self.audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert')
self.pipeline.add(self.audioconvert)

self.autoaudiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('autoaudiosink')
self.pipeline.add(self.autoaudiosink)

self.progressreport = Gst.ElementFactory.make('progressreport')
self.progressreport.set_property('update-freq', 1)
self.pipeline.add(self.progressreport)
```

All pipeline also already linked. But, I running out of idea how to do numpy array retrieval in real-time from the stream. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pipeline in the original question is designed to display video and play audio, so it uses the `autovideosink` and `autoaudiosink` elements, respectively. If you want your video frames to go to your application instead of to the screen, you need to use a different sink element, namely `appsink` instead of `autovideosink`.

```py
self.appsink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsink')
self.pipeline.add(self.appsink)
```

The `appsink` element has a signal called "new-sample" that you can connect to that fires when a new frame is available, if you enable appsink's "emit-signals" property.

```py
serf.appsink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
handler_id = self.appsink.connect("new-sample", self.__on_new_sample)
```

Then it's a matter of converting GStreamer's buffer format to a Numpy array.

```py
def __on_new_sample(self, app_sink):
    sample = app_sink.pull_sample()
    caps = sample.get_caps()

    # Extract the width and height info from the sample's caps
    height = caps.get_structure(0).get_value("height")
    width = caps.get_structure(0).get_value("width")

    # Get the actual data
    buffer = sample.get_buffer()
    # Get read access to the buffer data
    success, map_info = buffer.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
    if not success:
        raise RuntimeError("Could not map buffer data!")

    numpy_frame = np.ndarray(
        shape=(height, width, 3),
        dtype=np.uint8,
        buffer=map_info.data)

    # Clean up the buffer mapping
    buffer.unmap(map_info)
```

Note that this code makes certain assumptions about the frame data, namely that it's a 3-color format like RGB and that the color data will be unsigned 8-bit ints.

Comment: What about de complexity of this solution? Is it zero-copy?

Comment: My understanding is that it's zero-copy.